# php using mcrypt_create_iv

Tags: php, string, random, int, mcrypt

I want to create a random ints and strings in PHP and so I decided to use mcrypt_create_iv. It is written in manual that it uses /dev/random and /dev/urandom for randomness but I can't find a simple tutorial on how to generate random Int and String using this function. I tried some code but this function gives me unreadable characters. So please can you give me a simple  example of how properly I can use it?

Comment: `mcrypt_create_iv`'s purpose is not to generate random strings. Its purpose is to generate an cryptographic initialization vector (hence *mcrypt* and *iv*).

Comment: running base64_encode on the output of mcrypt_create_iv is also an option if you want a smaller character set.

Comment: Since Mcrypt has now been [removed](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mcrypt-viking-funeral) starting with PHP 7.2, you will only ever want to use PHP’s built-in functions `random_int` and `random_bytes`, the latter of which you can encode to a hexadecimal representation, Base64, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to generate random numbers, use [`mt_rand`](http://php.net/mt_rand):

```
$random = mt_rand(0, 999999);
```

If you want a string, you can pass the resulting integer through a hash function:

```
$random = mt_rand(0, 999999);
$random_string = sha1($random);
```

`mcrypt_create_iv` is used in cryptography. It is totally unrelated to your requirement.

If you're looking to use the random string in security components (salts, passwords, etc.), read from `/dev/urandom` like so:

```
$random = file_get_contents('/dev/urandom', false, null, 0, 10);
```

...where `10` is the length, then convert like this:

```
$string = bin2hex($random);
$number = current(unpack('L', $random));
```

Comment: Google it and you will found php gurus say, that it is NOT safe method. The only safe method is using /dev/urandom

Comment: @user1228636: Safety is relative. You didn't mention what you wanted it for, so unless you do that, I don't care whether it's safe or not according to your standards. You want random numbers? Use `mt_rand`. You want to read from `/dev/urandom`, just read from it.

Comment: I just don't know how to read from /dev/urandom. So I thought that mcrypt_create_iv was doing the job automatically. I was wrong...

Comment: @user1228636: `mcrypt_create_iv` does that, but that's not what it's used for. It would actually help if you could say what you plan on using these random numbers/strings for. Then I could actually tell if it's safe or not to use `mt_rand`.

Comment: I want to use it for salting, I need best randomness posibility for ints and strings. it will be cool if give me an example of using it to do my job.

Comment: @user1228636: That wasn't so hard now was it? :) I updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you, Thank you and Thank you very much, BUT echo ($number); gives me Array. it is array not int

Comment: sorry, for disturbing you so much, but can you please, tell me how to make sure that I will get numbers from my selected value? because returned values are 692661264, 226052807, 1733460338, -121292951, -674147318. Can you generate like from 1 to 100, I am thinking that I will need to use it for future. sorry again to disturb you so much

Comment: @user1228636: Yes it's because of PHP typing system. If you want a random number between 0 and 100, just use `mt_rand`. It is not "safe" anyway, because you only have 101 possibilities. And by the way, `mt_rand` is not "safe" if you want to generate numbers greater than 2^32. Below that, it's perfectly fine.

Comment: Yes you are right, I get random between 1, 255 so, what do you think, is there a way to fix this and get for example between 1 - 800 using dev/urandom? I am just curious

Comment: @user1228636: Like I said, use `mt_rand`. If your number is less than 32-bit long (i.e.: 4,294,967,296), then it doesn't make a difference. `/dev/urandom` can only give you ranges that are multiples of 8 bits. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_(computer_science)#Common_integral_data_types for details.

Answer (score 7):

Firstly, how do you want to use the random strings, what do you want to use them for? If it is for generating salts for passwords you can use this function to generate better random strings than those generated by uniqid() or mt_rand(). See [Secure Password Hashing](http://crackstation.net/hashing-security.html) and see code below on how to generate a random string using mcrypt_create_iv()). If you want the strings for user identification why not try out [UUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) instead.
The use of mcrypt_create_iv on its own will simply generate unreadable characters. To "convert" those unreadable characters to something readable use the bin2hex function like this:

```
$random_string = bin2hex(mcrypt_create_iv(30, [MCRYPT_DEV_RANDOM|MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM|MCRYPT_RAND]));
```

The "30" is the size of the initialization vector that you want to get. Remember, using MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM and MCRYPT_DEV_RANDOM on Windows machines with PHP versions older than the 5.3.0 release will not work. Use MCRYPT_RAND instead for such cases.

Comment: Thank you, you are the first that put a concise and clean example, i cant find any on the web.

Answer (score 0):

rand ( int $min , int $max )  use this for random numbers and for strings take a md5 or sha1 hash of the random number;

Comment: I want to use /dev/urandom because It is the safest method. that method is NOT safe at all