# WAMP hash not generating

Tags: php

The following code is not generating an output in WAMP on windows.

Works fine on MAMP.

Guessing it's a missing module or something.

```
$reportHash = str_replace(
        array('+','/','='),
        array('-','_',''),
        base64_encode(file_get_contents('/dev/urandom', null, null, -1, 16)));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `/dev/urandom` on Windows.

Use [`uniqid()`](http://php.net/uniqid) for a portable random string generator or [`mt_rand()`](http://php.net/mt_rand) for a portable random number generator.

Comment: Beat me to it!  Here is an SO question related to mt_rand(): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9446892/php-using-mcrypt-create-iv

Comment: @David, WAMP is a collection of software that makes it easy to run PHP, Apache and MySQL on Windows. They will be running on Windows though, not on UNIX. `/dev/urandom` is a file that exists on UNIX filesystems ([`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/file_get_contents) actually opens the file and reads from it), but no such file exists on Windows, so the read will fail. Using that file will limit the portability of your code to UNIX systems (such as Linux and Mac OS X).

Comment: Know of any good alternative to doing what I've done on UNIX on windows.

Comment: @David, sure, use `mt_rand()` to generate enough numbers between 0 and 255, then use [`chr()`](http://php.net/chr) to obtain the characters identified by the random numbers you're getting, to fill your string.